# IntelliJ reads old step definition & step undefined

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin

I use IntelliJ with Cucumber.
I have Cucumber plugin and Gherkin plugin.

Issue 1: When I update my step definition class and then run the test from the feature file, the test never picks up the new code from the step definition. (See attached image)
You can see that the output is the old:

```
Financial Times
HHHHHHHHHH
SEARCH FINANCIAL KEYBOARD: crypto
```

New output should be:
I click on the search button.
I type in the search keyword: crypto
I see the result.

Issue 2: When I add a new Gherkin step, it always generates step undefined. But the step definition for that Gherkin step is defined and linked.
But when I run it using the Junit runner class, it works!

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: You already reported this issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-326672. Please continue the communication there.